# How can I convert a List<int[]> to a 2D array?

Tags: java, list, matrix

I have a List of arrays  declared like this :

```
List<int[]> ls = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

Here I am trying to keep a list with arrays like this :
[ [1,2,3] ,[2,3],[4,5] ]

To add an array to this list I do this in a for loop:

```
int[] a = new int[2];
a[0] = arr[i];
a[1] = arr[i]+k;
ls.add(a);
```

I want to convert this list of arrays in a matrix that has 1 rows and list.size as colums like this :

```
[[0, -1], [-1, -2], [2, 1], [1, 0]]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, invoke [toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-):

```
// new double-dimension int array
//                   | conversion here
//                   |                  | specifying 1st dimension's size as list's 
//                   |                  | size
int[][] converted = ls.toArray(new int[ls.size()][]);

// test it
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(converted));
```

Comment: Hello.Shouldn't be   int[][] converted = ls.toArray(new int[1][ls.size()]);

Comment: @MarianaMitru no. Consider the first dimension is the list's own size, i.e. how many `int[]`s you have. The second dimension may be variable, depending on what's in each of your `int[]`s.